# define range of all but last of occupied cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets, range, google-sheets-formula

How can I define a range in Google Sheets to match all but the last occupied cell in a column? ie if column A is blank after A45, say, I want the range A1:A44. I have explored various constructs to find the row of the last occupied cell, eg

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))
```

How can I define the required range?

Comment: Could you share an example sheet to check what's the desired output? If you want to retrieve the values within the range you could use something like `=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(Sheetname!A:A,0))` however checking an actual example would be better that way we can understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: To explain, here is a simplified example. It is a simple account. I am no accountant and there may be a much simpler way to do what I am trying to do. 
On arbitrary dates the account is partially settled, and a new sheet starts. On a given date, I want to create a sum of all the debits within the last year. So Sheet2!F5 contains the start date (1 year ago) and G5 contains the sum. 
I am trying to exclude the C/f line from Sheet1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tj5F05eEDahSUV-qqMhd0o82BulxhLZ0rUZ5XRByEno/edit#gid=0

Comment: Could you share a public spreadsheet? it seems the one you shared can't be accessed.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo is there a way of sharing on this site? Or how would you recommend me to share?

Answer (score 0):

take:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>"")))
```